# How to force headers to be sent?

Tags: php, http-headers

I have built a progressive file download (download begins while file is still being generated), but some file formats don't support this. To solve this I simply wait until the file is generated and then send it whole.

The problem with this workaround is, that the download dialog pops up when sending starts after the file was generated. This is especially annoying when file generation takes a couple minutes. I suspect that the headers are not sent until actual output starts.

I've tried doing `ob_flush(); flush();` right before waiting for generation to finish to no avail. Apparently it refuses to send headers when there is no buffered content.

So, how do I force the HTTP-headers to be sent to the client?

Comment: Have you tried `ob_end_clean()` and `header()`? You may then send the headers followed by contents to be echoed.

Comment: @ai64 Nop, `ob_end_clean()` did nothing. I already have a couple `header()` calls to prepare the browser for the incoming download.

Comment: Do you have several levels of buffering?  What does `ob_get_level()` return?

Comment: @TerjeD. `ob_get_level()` returns `1`.